# Using methods defined in __init__.py within the module

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
lib\
--__init__.py
--foo.py
--bar.py
```

Inside foo and bar, there are seperate methods that both need the same method. For instance:

foo:

```
def method1():
    win()
```

bar:

```
def method2(number):
    if number < 0:
        lose()
    else:
        win()
```

__init__:

```
def win():
    print "You Win!"

def lose():
    print "You Lose...."
```

Is there a way to use the win and lose methods within the **init**.py in the modules respective subfiles, or do I have to create another file within the folder and have foo and bar import that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just import the `__init__.py` module (via either an absolute or relative import, it doesn't really matter).

I never like relative imports, so I'd do so with `import mypackage` in `mypackage.foo`, which imports the `__init__.py` just like a relative import does, and then using it there. I also don't like putting anything in `__init__.py` though generally, so perhaps you should consider the shared common file anyhow.

Comment: There are clear reasons for using relative imports, with maintainability being the primary one. See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports). (I agree with the advice to keep `__init__.py` as empty as possible, though.)

Comment: I'm aware of the reasons there, I just don't think they're good (or outweigh the reasons for absolute imports) :).

Answer (score 7):

Use relative imports:

```
from . import win, lose
```

Comment: Relative imports are not really the point here, the point is just that you need to import `__init__.py`, however you'd like to do so.

Comment: Julian, easel solution works. `from . import win, lose` imports "win" and "lose" from ".", which is the current package = `__init__.py`.

Comment: @Bakuriu of course it works, I just said it's not really the point here, the point is just to import the module containing the functions -- how you do so is up to you :).

Comment: Ah okay. I misunderstood your comment. Next time I'll read twice before replying :s
By the way, I, instead, like relative imports... _de gustibus non est disputandum_ :)